# Problema con FPDF

Tags: php, mysql, pdf

Que tal Amigos muy buena noche, tengo un pequeño problema con la herramienta FPDF en mi sitio web, la cosa es que en localhost todo funciona perfectamente, pero al llevar mi php al hosting online y solicitar el pdf la página se queda en blanco totalmente sin imprimir ningún resultado o error.

mi código php es el siguiente:

```
<? @$id = @$_GET['id']; ?>
 <?

include('config.php');

@$userid = $_SESSION["id_usuario"];

$link=Conectarse();

 $query = "SELECT * from orders WHERE `id` = '$id' ORDER BY `orders`.`id` DESC";     // Esta linea hace la consulta 
    $result = mysql_query($query);
   $registro = mysql_fetch_array($result);
   $factura = $registro['id']; 
   $cantidad = $registro['cantidad']; 
   $cprod = $registro['cprod'];
   $pbase = $registro['pbase'];
   $cenvio = $registro['cenvio'];
   $costo = $cantidad * $pbase;
   $envio  = $cantidad * $cenvio;
   $producto = $registro['producto']; 
   $sum = $pbase + $cenvio;
   $total = $sum * $cantidad; 

?>
<?
    $cid = $registro['cid'];
    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM clientes WHERE `id` = '$cid'";
    $query2 = mysql_query($consulta);
    $array = mysql_fetch_array($query2);
    $establecimiento = $array['establecimiento'];
    $calle = $array['calle'];
    $numero = $array['numero'];
    $colonia = $array['colonia'];
    $cd = $array['ciudad'];

    $consulta3 = "SELECT * FROM regiones WHERE `id` = '$cd'";
    $query3 = mysql_query($consulta3);
    $array3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3);
    $ciudad = $array3['ciudad'];
    $estado = $array3['estado'];

    $consulta4 = "SELECT * FROM productos WHERE `id` = '$producto'";
    $query4 = mysql_query($consulta4);
    $array4 = mysql_fetch_array($query4);
    $nproducto = $array4['nombre'];

    ?>
<?php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');

$pdf=new FPDF();
///var_dump(get_class_methods($pdf));

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","13");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Cerveceria Montoro SA. de CV.",0,0,"L");
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","18");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"Orden de Compra No. $factura",0,1,"R");
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","I","11");
$pdf->Cell(0,5,"Nacida Para Disfrutar.",0,0,"L");
$pdf->Ln(15);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","11");
$pdf->Cell(0,5,"C. Camino Viejo a Calvillo",0,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(0,5,"No. 517-A, Fracc. Villas de Monte Claro.",0,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(0,5,"Jesus Maria, Aguascalientes. CP. 20994",0,1,"L");
$pdf->Cell(0,5,"Tel - (449)9049760",0,1,"L");
$pdf->Image('img/logo.png',130,25,50);
$pdf->Ln(20);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","20");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"$establecimiento",1,1);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","","15");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"$calle No. $numero, $colonia.",1,1);
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"$ciudad, $estado.",1,1);
$pdf->Ln(15);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","13");
$pdf->Cell(0,10,"PEDIDO",1,1,"C");
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","B","10");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,"CANTIDAD",0,0);
$pdf->Cell(120,10,"DESCRIPCION",0,0);
$pdf->Cell(20,10,"COSTO",0,1);
$pdf->SetFont("Arial","","10");
$pdf->Cell(30,10,"$cantidad",0,0);
$pdf->Cell(120,10,"$nproducto",0,0);
$pdf->Cell(20,10,"$ $costo MXN.",0,1);
$pdf->Cell(30,10,"1",0,0);
$pdf->Cell(120,10,"Envio a $ciudad, $estado .",0,0);
$pdf->Cell(20,10,"$ $envio MXN.",0,1);
$pdf->Ln(15);
$pdf->Cell(170,10,"TOTAL: $ $total MXN.",0,1,"R");
$pdf->Output();
?>
```

Les agradeceré puedan orientarme un poco :) Saludos!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

deberías probar pasando los parametros necesarios al método OUTPUT() de FPDF...

podes ver la documentación oficial del método OUTPUT() en:

http://www.fpdf.org/es/doc/output.htm

dependiendo de que quieres hacer con la salida, el primer parámetro puede ser:

**I**: si quieres que el navegador intente abrir el PDF.

**D**: si quieres pasarlo al navegador para que inicie una descarga del archivo con el nombre puesto en el segundo parametro.

**F**: guarda el fichero cono local (osea en el server, debes tener cuidado con esta opcion ya que en la carpeta del servidor debes tener los permisos en 777, sino no guardara nada).

**S**: produce la salida como una cadena.

**Por ejemplo:**

```
$pdf->Output('D','archivo.pdf');
```

produce que el navegador inicie la descarga de la salida pdf dentro de un archivo llamado "archivo.pdf"

Espero te sirva. Saludos!

Comment: Hola Mauro, agradezco tu apoyo! ya he probado con todos los parámetros que me sugeriste, y desafortunadamente no obtuve ningún resultado llamando al pdf desde mi hosting, más sin embargo trabajando localmente si pude comprobar cada parámetro. Sinceramente desconozco a que pueda deberse esto, no produce el PDF, simplemente la página se queda totalmente en blanco.

Comment: Lo resolví, eliminando `@$userid = $_SESSION["id_usuario"];` variables que en realidad no necesitaba, gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Me alegro mucho que funcione tu código... debes tener cuidado con el uso de @, ya que este símbolo suprime Warnings y Mensajes de error que pueden ayudarte con tus problemas de código. Saludos!